# Best Way to Verify LinkedIn OAuth2/Publishing API is up?

Tags: android, web-applications, linkedin-api

I'm making an app that hits LinkedIn on behalf of my app's users to do things like go through the OAuth2 process and post updates to their LinkedIn profile. These are some of the URLs I'm using:

`https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization`
`https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken`
`https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/{userIdNumber}/shares?format=json`

I'm trying to design something that will verify that these URLs have not changed and/or become not supported anymore, but also something that will verify that LinkedIn is not simply having a service outage (ex. 500 response code returned or something of that nature) with one of these URLs. Is there a good way to do this? I'm concerned about simply hitting the URLs on a regular basis (a couple times per hour, for example) and analysing the responses because of throttling limits. I also don't want to have my Developer account flagged for suspicious activity.

Comment: Ideally, you dont have to check for Linkedin API service outage. You can have all sorts of exceptions covered in your code for each requests and act accordingly.

Comment: Hi Rifaj, thanks for your reply! What we're concerned about more than anything is that maybe the LinkedIn URL we're hitting changes unexpectedly or they completely change their return data type and this breaks our code. We want to be able to notify our developers immediately without having to wait to hear from a bunch of customers that their app isn't working.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for something like that?

Comment: Any major change in the URL and data type will be announced well before it comes into effect so that developers can make changes in the apps without affecting the user. They are doing the same for the current partnership integration transition. Keep following the LinkedIn developer blog for any changes coming up that affects your app.